# Adding scope to get objects in reverse order of their created time in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, scope

I'm new to Ruby on rails and programming.
I am working on a exercise where I have a **Post** model,and I need to add a new **scope** to it to retrieve its objects in reverse order of their created time.

Here is my model code:

```or-tag-here
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :comments
      belongs_to :user 
scope :ordered_by_reverse_order, -> { order('created_at DESC').reverse} 
end
```

I have tried `{reverse('created_at DESC')}` as well, both didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

scope :ordered_by_reverse_order, -> { order('created_at ASC') }

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want [`reverse_order`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/reverse_order) (Rails 3+).

```
scope :ordered_by_reverse_order, -> { order(:created_at).reverse_order }
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use class methods when defining scopes for models on rails.
This is the exact same as your scope method, but personally I think its cleaner.

Try ordering your posts in ascending order instead of descending:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  belongs_to :user 

  def self.reversed
    order('created_at ASC')
  end 
end

# ASC
# Fri, 20 Feb 2015 08:41:26 UTC +00:00
# Fri, 20 Feb 2015 08:42:25 UTC +00:00
# Fri, 20 Feb 2015 08:43:53 UTC +00:00

# DESC
# Fri, 20 Feb 2015 12:43:25 UTC +00:00
# Fri, 20 Feb 2015 08:44:48 UTC +00:00
# Fri, 20 Feb 2015 08:43:53 UTC +00:00
```

Executing following command should return what you want:

```
Post.reversed
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also just sort by `DESC` instead of using `.reverse_order` like this:

`default_scope { order(created_at: :desc) }`